# How to run threads concurrently in Jmeter using loop controller

Tags: multithreading, loops, controller, jmeter

I made a Jmeter script like one thread in it login then my transaction and logout. I have put login n only once controller and transaction in loop controller. But when I execute concurrent thread some threads are failing as csrf token is not matching sequentially. I extract csrf token using regular expression. For 1-2 users it is working fine but more threads it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some debug logging to your test, i.e.

1. Save CSRF Token value into .jtl results file using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property
2. [Save all the responses into the .jtl results file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/useful-jmeter-properties-save-results-save-world), you can do this by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
   ```
3. Inspect the response and the CSRF Token variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination - it should be 100% match for each virtual user and different threads (virtual users) must have different CSRF Token values.